# Changing width constraint causes conflicts

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, nslayoutconstraint

I have an interface set up with constraints, with a menu bar, collection view, followed by a label, and finally a table view.  I am trying to change the width of the collection view via an outlet to the width constraint.  However, when I make this change, the collection view seems to move upward and I receive a conflict error.  The error says there is a conflict between:

```
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7ff61a519020 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7ff61a564eb0(64)]>",

"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7ff61a555a00 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7ff61a564eb0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7ff61a5620c0 )>",

"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff61a5665e0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7ff61a564eb0]-(0)-[UICollectionView:0x7ff61b05ea00]>",

"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7ff61a4e1630 h=-&- v=-&- 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Top' V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7ff61a5620c0]   (Names: '|':UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x7ff61a70c4e0 )>"
```

The constraint being broken is

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff61a5665e0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7ff61a564eb0]-(0)-[UICollectionView:0x7ff61b05ea00]>
```

What is causing this?

Comment: it seems that collection view's top constraint is not given properly...please verify top constraint of collection view.

Comment: make sure you have proper outlet taken because width and top constraint not have connection in autolayout

Comment: Would the fact that it's right under the nav bar have any effect?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the reason for the error was I was attempting to call layoutIfNeeded within viewDidLoad.